# Compute $\iint_ S \text{F}.\vec n\; \text{d}S$, with and without using Divergence theorem

Tags: vector-fields, multiple-integral, divergence-theorem

Given a vector field $$\text{F}=(xz^2)\vec i+(x^2y-z^3)\vec j+(2xy+y^2z)\vec k$$

---

- How to describe $\Sigma_1$ in cylindrical coordinates?
- How to generally find $\vec n$?

And $S$ is the sphere half sphere $z= \sqrt {4-x^2-y^2}$ and $z=0$, then compute $$\iint_ S \text{F}\cdot\vec  n\; \text{d}S$$

---

From Divergence theorem I know that the double integral is indeed:

$$\begin{align}
\iiint_V \nabla \cdot \text{F} \;\text{d} V &= \iiint_V x^2+y^2+z^2 \;\text{d} V\\[1ex]
&= \int_{0}^{2 \pi}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt {4- \rho^2
}}(\rho^2+z^2)\rho \;\text{d}z\text{d}\rho\text{d}\theta\\[1ex]
&=\frac{64\pi}{5}\end{align}$$

If I was going to compute $\iint_ S \text{F}\cdot\vec  n\; \text{d}S$ directly without using Divergence theorem, then how I could proceed?

---

The surface $S$ can be written as $$S= \Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2$$

Where $$\Sigma_1= \left\{(\rho \cos\theta,\rho  \sin\theta
,z):  0\le \theta  \le 
 2\pi , 0 \le z  \le \sqrt{4-\rho^2} \right\}$$
$$\Sigma_2= \left\{(2 \cos\theta,2 \sin\theta,0): 0\le \theta \le  2\pi \right\}$$
And $$\vec n_1=\frac{\partial \Sigma_1}{\partial \theta}×  \frac{\partial \Sigma_1}{\partial z}=\langle \rho\cos\theta,\rho\sin\theta,0 \rangle $$

So:$$\iint_ {\Sigma_1} \text{F}\cdot\vec  n_1\; \text{d}S$$$$=\int_{0}^{2 \pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-\rho^2} } z^{2}r^{2}\cos^{2}\theta+\left(r^{2}\cos^{2}\theta\sin\theta-z^{3}\right)r\sin\theta\;\text{d}z\text{d}\theta\tag{I} $$

And $$\vec n_2=\frac{\partial \Sigma_2}{\partial \theta}\times  \frac{\partial \Sigma_2}{\partial z}=\langle 0,0,0 \rangle $$

So:$$\iint_ {\Sigma_2} \text{F}\cdot\vec  n_2\; \text{d}S=0 \tag{II}$$

Now we need to add $(\text{I})$ and $(\text{II})$

$$\iint_ S \text{F}\cdot\vec  n\; \text{d}S=\iint_ {\Sigma_1} \text{F}\cdot\vec  n_1\; \text{d}S+\iint_ {\Sigma_2} \text{F}\cdot\vec  n_2\; \text{d}S$$

However I doubt if $\Sigma_1$ describes the half sphere correctly.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4187556

Comment: Also it is half sphere. To apply divergence theorem, you have to close the surface with a disk at $z=0$ and if the question is to find flux through the spherical surface, then subtract flux through  the disk. For direct surface integral, parametrize the surface as $(x, y, \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2})$.

Comment: The parameterizations for $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ should involve only two variables each. I would suggest using spherical coordinates for $\Sigma_1$, namely $\langle2\cos\theta\sin\varphi,2\sin\theta\sin\varphi,2\cos\varphi\rangle$ with $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ and $\varphi\in\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$, and polar for $\Sigma_2$, $\langle\rho\cos\theta,\rho\sin\theta,0\rangle$ with $\rho\in[0,2]$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's work on $\Sigma_1$, we consider the parametrization,

$$x=r\cos \theta, y=r\sin \theta, z=\sqrt{4-r^2}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta \\ \sin \theta \\ \frac{-r}{\sqrt{4-r^2}}\end{bmatrix}  \times \begin{bmatrix} -r\sin \theta \\ r \cos \theta \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{r^2\cos \theta}{\sqrt{4-r^2}} \\ \frac{r^2 \sin \theta}{\sqrt{4-r^2}}\\ r\end{bmatrix}$$

$$F(r, \theta) =\begin{bmatrix} r(4-r^2)\cos \theta \\ r^3\cos^2 \theta \sin \theta - (4-r^2)^\frac32\\ 2r^2\sin \theta \cos \theta + r^2 \sin ^2 \theta\sqrt{4-r^2}\end{bmatrix}$$

\begin{align}
&\int \int_{\Sigma_1} F \cdot \vec{n}_1 dS\\
&=\int_0^2 r^3\sqrt{4-r^2}\, dr \int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2 \theta \, d\theta + \int_0^2 \frac{r^5}{\sqrt{4-r^2}}\, dr \int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta \, d\theta + \int_0^2r^3 \sqrt{4-r^2}\, dr \int_0^{2\pi} \sin^2 \theta \, d\theta \\
&= 2\pi \int_0^{2}r^3\sqrt{4-r^2}\, dr + \frac{\pi}4 \int_0^2 \frac{r^5}{\sqrt{4-r^2}}\, dr\\
&= 2\pi \left(\frac{64}{15} \right) + \frac{\pi}{4} \left( \frac{256}{15}\right)\\
&=3\pi \left(\frac{64}{15} \right)\\
&= \frac{64\pi}{5}
\end{align}

Now, let's work on $\Sigma_2$,

$$x=r\cos \theta, y=r\sin \theta, z=0$$

$$ \begin{bmatrix} -r\sin \theta \\ r\cos\theta \\ 0\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta \\ \sin \theta \\ 0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ -r\end{bmatrix}$$

\begin{align}
&\int\int_{\Sigma_2} F \cdot \vec{n}_2 dS\\
&= \int_0^2-r^3 \, dr \int_0^{2\pi} \sin \theta \cos \theta\, d\theta
\\&=0
\end{align}